# .NET Unable to reopen Serial Port after usb reconnection

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I am trying to reopen a serial port after a device is unpluged and pluged. I have designed this little code to test. However, it throws IOException when repluguing the device and opening the port.

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM6",115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
sp.Open();
Console.WriteLine("OPEN");
await Task.Delay(5000); //Here i disconnect the usb
sp.Close();
Console.WriteLine("CLOSE");
await Task.Delay(5000); //Here i reconnect the usb
sp.Open(); //Here it throws IOException, resource already in use
Console.WriteLine("OPEN");
```

I have done the same test in python and happens exactly the same

```
import serial as s
import time

ser = s.Serial('COM6',115200,parity=s.PARITY_NONE,\
        stopbits=s.STOPBITS_ONE,\
        bytesize=s.EIGHTBITS)

#ser.open()
print('Open')
time.sleep(5) #here I unplug the usb
ser.close()
print('close')
time.sleep(5) #here I plug the usb
ser.open() #here throws exception
print('open')
```

Comment: if u remove the awaits, then u have to breakpoint before the close and before the second open to have time to unplug and replug otherwise the test is not valid

Comment: I assume that you need to create a new SerialPort instance in that case.

Comment: @Ralf if i create the object before the second open happens the same

Comment: Looking at the source code that should not help. How do you disconnect? Just unplugging or removing the device via the OS?

Comment: @Ralf just unplugging, shall i try something else?

Comment: I was thinking of the eject feature you would need for an usb drive. If you use some sort of "usb to serial port" driver (often called virtual COM Port driver) here you may want to look at the docs of that if it has an equivalent feature.

Comment: Have you checked if it is the same COM Port? Sometimes it changes

Comment: @zTim I have just checked that with the package SerialPortStream it works good, but with system.IO.Ports it has the described behaviour. It is possible that the official library is buged?

Comment: @zTim it is the same port com6

Comment: The issue that you've encountered seems to be mentioned in the [SerialPortStream ReadMe](https://github.com/jcurl/RJCP.DLL.SerialPortStream#21-issues-with-ms-serial-port): _Closing a serial port, then reopening it generally causes problems_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official MS serial port library has a bug in the close in which it does not really close the serial port as reported in https://github.com/jcurl/RJCP.DLL.SerialPortStream#21-issues-with-ms-serial-port which is an alternative library for serial port operations.

This library is installed through a NuGet package and creates a SerialPortStream object which inherits from Stream so it can be used as the official SerialPort.BaseStream from the official MS library.

A little example is the following one using tasks and asyncrhonous operations, but it also can be used with event handlers.

```
SerialPortStream sps = new SerialPortStream("COM6", 115200, 8, Parity.None, StopBits.One);
byte[] bytes_buff = new byte[300];
sps.Open();
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        int n_bytes = await sps.ReadAsync(bytes_buff.AsMemory(0, 300)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        byte[] not_empty_bytes = bytes_buff[0..n_bytes];
        Console.WriteLine("\nFrame: " + BitConverter.ToString(not_empty_bytes) + "\n");
    }
});

await sps.WriteAsync(new byte[] { .... });
```

This example is a simple snippet but the serial port should be closed before exiting the program as well as the task used to read async with a cancellation token.